# WM_CLOSE in modal message loop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using a special message loop for a custom dialog box. When the dialog box is open and the window is closed, I would like to reach the second if below, if(msg.message == WM_CLOSE).

```
for(;;)
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
    {
        if(msg.message == WM_CLOSE)
        {
            GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            if(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }

            if(msg.message == msgEnd)
                break;
        }
    }
```

The problem is the code in this if is never reached. I tried replacing WM_CLOSE with another message to see if the loop was the problem, but the other message worked fine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that WM_CLOSE is sent, and the other message is posted.

`GetMessage` and `PeekMessage` only operate on posted messages (those posted with `PostMessage`). If a message is not posted but sent via `SendMessage`, it's handled immediately inside `PeekMessage` or `GetMessage`, so you can not get `MSG` struct for it.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check when the message is sent, and execute the code inside that if? I need a way to handle the situation where the dialog box is open and the window is closed.

Comment: In WindowProc of the target window, or from a CallWindowProc hook. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You may use `InSendMessage`  or `InSendMessageEx` to check if message was sent or posted.